# How to setup permission to single project on Jira

Tags: jira, jira-agile

We have multiple projects but want to have single user to be able to see and work in just one project in Jira Software Cloud

Answer (score 0):

It will be good to have new dedicated permission scheme. You may start by copy the default one:
     [image]

Permissions can be based on Project Role or Group and depend on what will be your preference to manage. 
     [image]

If they are set on "Project role" as given on picture below if you is set to be in "Developer" role of certain project he will have browse permissions to it and each project that this permission scheme can be configured with users in certain roles and so these users will be the one granted with permissions
     [image]

Target Project needs to be updated to use the new the new permission scheme .
[image]

It will be good to change default permission scheme to be more restrictive i.e. probably just user group admins to have access to projects that are using it.

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

The trick is to restrict access to all your projects apart from the one you want them to be able to see.

Then create a group that has permission to access the restricted projects.

Finally, add all your users to the group that has access *apart from* the single user that you want to restrict.

Answer (score 0):

Create a new project role "Team member".
Copy the default permission scheme and replace "Application access - Any logged in user" with "Project role - Team Member".
Apply the new permission scheme to your project.
Add the user to the project under the role "Team Member".

Caveat: some permissions may be lost because of the "Any logged in user" permission removal which is sooo generic it hurts. So you need to check that existing users still have the access they expect. First step would be to add them to the project under the "Team Member" role.